# How to use Ngu Carousel

Tags: angular, carousel

How can i use Ngu Carousel and show 3 ngu-item in 1 row? Or can smb recommend some native angular carousel for card-item with loop and animation.

Documentation of Ngu Carousel shows this example:

```
this.carouselOne = {
      grid: {xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 1, lg: 1, all: 0},
      slide: 1,
      speed: 400,
      interval: 4000,
      point: {
        visible: true
      },
      load: 2,
      touch: true,
      loop: true,
      custom: 'banner'
    }
```

But if I change `slide` or another property - there is no changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to define the no of items in grid.
grid: {xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 1, lg: 1, all: 0} property will set 1 ngu tile item in xs, sm , md and lg respectively. If you don't want such a behaviour, u can set the fixed width for carousel in the {all : } property. But make sure to 0 the others in xs,sm,md and lg. 
For more details on ngu carousel , => https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Setting 1 for grid doe not show 1 item, grid: { xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 1, lg: 1, all: 0 }, it shows 2 items

Comment: Fixed by setting with in inline CSS to item

Answer (score 0):

You can show three `ngu-item` in one row using:

```
grid: {xs: 3, sm: 3, md: 3, lg: 3, all: 0},
```